# How can I sample from a dataframe weighted by groupby column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sampling

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) is a sampling method.
I tried:

```
sample=2000 
sample_df = df.groupby('prefix').sample(n=sample, random_state=1)
```

It groups `df` by `prefix` and for each group, it samples 2k items. I have 9 groups. I want to sample 18k but weighted by the number in each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here is one way:

```
sample = 2000
col_name = "prefix"

probs = df[col_name].map(df[col_name].value_counts())
sample_df = df.sample(n=sample, weights=probs)
```

`probs` are the corresponding (unnormalized) weights for each value in `prefix` column, and we sample according to that.

---

Steps on some sample data:

```
>>> df

       B         C         D
0   this  0.469112 -0.861849
1   this -0.282863 -2.104569
2  other -1.509059 -0.494929
3   view -1.135632  1.071804
4  other  1.212112  0.721555
5  other -0.173215 -0.706771
6   this  0.119209 -1.039575
7   view -1.044236  0.271860
8  other  0.322124  2.010234

>>> col_name = "B"
>>> sample = 4

>>> counts = df[col_name].value_counts()
>>> counts

other    4
this     3
view     2
Name: B, dtype: int64

>>> probs = df[col_name].map(counts)
>>> probs

0    3
1    3
2    4
3    2
4    4
5    4
6    3
7    2
8    4
Name: B, dtype: int64

# seeing side-by-side with df.B
>>> pd.concat([df.B, probs], axis=1)

0   this  3
1   this  3
2  other  4
3   view  2
4  other  4
5  other  4
6   this  3
7   view  2
8  other  4
```

i.e., each value in `col_name` is attached a number which, in relative, measures its weight inferred from its count in the column.

```
# sampling:
>>> sample_df = df.sample(n=sample, weights=probs, random_state=1284)
>>> sample_df

       B         C         D
6   this  0.119209 -1.039575
3   view -1.135632  1.071804
2  other -1.509059 -0.494929
5  other -0.173215 -0.706771
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you werrite it so that I can pass any other field than `prefix`? moreover where do you count them by grouping them?

Comment: @Ahmad I rearranged for giving any name in lieue of `prefix` as the grouping variable and also tried to explain the process of forming counts & unnormalized weights; hope it helps.